# Nitrogen fertilisation expressed as nitrogen equivalent

Tags: analytical-chemistry

In a plant pathology paper I found levels of fertilisation applied in the experiment expressed as nitrogen equivalent.
Reporting the exact phrase:

> Nitrogen fertilisation with 8.6 g of nitrogen equivalent …

I found that equivalent weight for an element would be its atomic weight divided by its valency so, if I'm not wrong, equivalent weight for N would be ~4.67 g

What does this mean? 
How much fertiliser was applied e.g. using ammonium sulfate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is referring only to the mass of elemental nitrogen available, rather than the total mass of fertilizer. In your case, ammonium sulfate is 21% nitrogen (see the table [here](http://extension.psu.edu/agronomy-guide/cm/sec2/sec28) for other fertilizers and [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labeling_of_fertilizer) for more information on fertilizer composition), which gives ~40.95g ammonium sulfate.